# Selenium: Getting error unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: selenium-webdriver

We are running Selenium Test from Jenkins pointing to our application deployed on Linux VM and getting the below error intermittently:

```
unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.64)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'kube-agent-q0ptq', ip: '10.42.2.232', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_282'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 111.0.5563.64, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.klD2sR}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:33164}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 01b6be9377dfb885bd9332dae8532195cde747e7bab5c232ae24f08e1926e15a
```

We tried clearing browser cache and but still getting same error.